# Subview bind to parent view in NSLayoutContraint SWIFT

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, swift, nslayoutconstraint

I'm very new to SWIFT and Mac development. Now I'm trying to use the NSLayoutContraint.

```
var boardView:NSView = NSView()
boardView.wantsLayer = true
boardView.layer!.backgroundColor = NSColor.redColor().CGColor

//boardView.setFrameSize(NSSize(width: 200, height: 200))
//boardView.setFrameOrigin(NSPoint(x: 50, y: 50))
self.view.addSubview(boardView)
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boardView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boardView, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0))
println(self.view.frame)
println(boardView.frame)
```

These codes stay in ViewController.viewDidLoad(), but the window can't be displayed after I run the code. And the console output is:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 600.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Then I set the boardView's width and height (uncomment line 5, 6). The view could be displayed now, but the window size is constraint to the boardView, not the boardView fit to outer window.

Now I'm very confused about that. Many thanks for help!

### First update

I copy the println to viewDidLayout(), and the output is below:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 600.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

Some errors/warnings happened.

```
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const: conn 0x4fc23 token 0x11ffffffffff2ad
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: Backtrace (at 790422):
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  0   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff90873501 CGSBacktraceCreate + 59
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  1   CoreGraphics                        0x00007fff908c8244 _ZN16CGSUpdateManager14disable_updateEv + 84
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  2   AppKit                              0x00007fff97dcdd15 -[NSWindow disableScreenUpdatesUntilFlush] + 127
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  3   AppKit                              0x00007fff97dcc95a -[NSView(NSInternal) geometryInWindowDidChange] + 185
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  4   AppKit                              0x00007fff97dcc581 -[NSView _invalidateFocus] + 437
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  5   AppKit                              0x00007fff97de9e67 -[NSView setFrameSize:] + 1735
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  6   AppKit                              0x00007fff97e5f87e -[NSThemeFrame setFrameSize:] + 473
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  7   AppKit                              0x00007fff97de8f83 -[NSView setFrame:] + 464
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  8   AppKit                              0x00007fff97e5537f -[NSView resizeWithOldSuperviewSize:] + 1206
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  9   AppKit                              0x00007fff97f5bd15 -[NSView layoutSubtreeIfNeeded] + 810
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  10  AppKit                              0x00007fff97f5b8ba _NSViewLayoutSubtreesThatUseAutolayoutIfNeeded + 71
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  11  AppKit                              0x00007fff97f5b841 -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) _layoutViewTree] + 84
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  12  AppKit                              0x00007fff97f7ad3d -[NSWindow(NSConstraintBasedLayout) layoutIfNeeded] + 246
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  13  AppKit                              0x00007fff97e1f52e _handleWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraints + 612
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  14  AppKit                              0x00007fff98555171 __83-[NSWindow _postWindowNeedsDisplayOrLayoutOrUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled]_block_invoke1540 + 46
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  15  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9295d127 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 23
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  16  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9295d080 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  17  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9294f188 __CFRunLoopRun + 872
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  18  CoreFoundation                      0x00007fff9294ebd8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 296
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  19  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9900456f RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 235
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  20  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff990041ee ReceiveNextEventCommon + 179
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  21  HIToolbox                           0x00007fff9900412b _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  22  AppKit                              0x00007fff97e1c8ab _DPSNextEvent + 978
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  23  AppKit                              0x00007fff97e1be58 -[NSApplication nextEventMatchingMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 346
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  24  AppKit                              0x00007fff97e11af3 -[NSApplication run] + 594
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  25  AppKit                              0x00007fff97d8e244 NSApplicationMain + 1832
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  26  GameBegin_Mac                       0x000000010000df0d main + 109
Aug 31 19:14:33 Hans-Bogenmacher.local GameBegin_Mac[28780] <Warning>: void CGSUpdateManager::log() const:  27  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff967715c9 start + 1
```

### Second update

I changed the constraints to:

```
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boardView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterX, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boardView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.CenterY, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .CenterY, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boardView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Width, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Width, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0))
self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: boardView!, attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Height, relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal, toItem: self.view, attribute: .Height, multiplier: 0.8, constant: 0))
```

But it's no use, the console output is:

```
(0.0, 0.0, 800.0, 480.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0)
```

### Third update

Just call boardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false and it works! Thank you!

But now I can't finish the requirement:

```
boardView.frame.width = self.view.frame.width * 0.8
boardView.frame.centerX = self.view.frame.centerX
boardView.frame.height = self.view.frame.height * 0.1
boardView.frame.top = self.view.frame.height * 0.2
```

Now I knew how to do lines 1, 2, 3, but I can't bind Top to Height, how to do line 4? Thanks!

Comment: Don't manually set frame values if you're using layout constraints. The constraints don't immediately change the frame values. You can inspect the updated frame values by moving your `println` statements to `viewDidLayout()`.

Comment: Thanks. But I still can't find a way to make it work. I copy the println to viewDidLayout() as you said, but the output is: (Watch my question)

Comment: You're only constraining the board view's size (width and height). You also need to constrain its position.

Comment: First, you have to do `boardView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false`. Any programmatically-created view that's going to be positioned by auto layout needs that. If that doesn't fix it, how is `self.view` related to the window's `contentView` (e.g. immediate subview or …)? Also, what constraints are there between them?